# Ada - list of lists

Tags: list, generics, ada

I am working on an ADA project.
Essentially what I need to do is I create a list in which I the first node is the main node or tower and every consecutive node is a tower than the main head is connected to.

So suppose I have a list like A -> B -> D -> E -> F, it means that the tower A is connected to tower B, D, E and F.

Now I also need to have a list to store all the main towers. So suppose I have A ->B -> D -> E -> F, and I have C->X->Y->Q, and E->P->R, the list of lists should be like:

A-> C-> E ( essentially the list of all the main nodes).

i need to do this using generic type lists.

I know this is a bit confusing.
But what should I do about it? Ada is so confusing to me.

Thanks in advance guys :)

Comment: For building lists of lists, take a look at (Ada-2005) Ada.Containers, e.g. chapter 22 in John Barnes "Programming in Ada-2005". Using Containers takes a bit of practice (in my opinion), but works a treat. You may find either doubly linked lists, or indefinite vectors, or a combination, to be most suitable.

Comment: Oh, ok. I forgot to mention that we have been specifically asked to not use Ada - 2005.
We have to use Ada - 95. So any option with that?
Like basically one list needs to be a list of strings and the other a list of string lists.

Comment: Yuck. Is this an exercise in putting people off Ada? ... hehe, alternatively, is there any explicit injunction against Ada-2012? :-)

Comment: You have two towers E; are they the same tower?

Comment: Yes, both the Es' represent the same tower.

Comment: Is this a classroom exercise where you're trying to learn how data structures are put together, or something like that?  It would be helpful to know that, before we just go pointing you to someone else's pre-written package.

Comment: I don't see what is the problem here - once you have generic list you instantiate it with String or whatever type you are using to represent towers thus getting Tower_List package. And then you just instantiate it once again using Tower_List.List (or whatever the name for your type) thus getting List_Of_Tower_Lists.

Comment: It is a classroom exercise. So, I was able to make the data structure for myself and it worked fine.
But now I have another doubt. As mentioned above, I have a list and its connections. and Now i need to traverse these lists to find out if a connection is possible. For example: I have A ->B -> D -> E -> F, and I have C->X->Y->Q, and E->P->R.
If i am asked is A ->R possible answer should be true. Since A -> E -> R.
My doubt is what approach should I use? BFS? Recursion? What will be the best one?

Comment: "The goal of this project is write resuable, abstract data types".  Have you designed a sensible abstract data structure for the problem?  (Your question doesn't quite sound like it.)

Comment: I think you should re-read the first sentence of the second paragraph of the "Approach" section of the project.

Answer (score 1):

If you're allowed to use someone else's Ada 95 container library, you could try the [Ada 95 Booch Components](https://sourceforge.net/projects/booch95/). If you (are allowed to) do this, don't use the Lists packages, use Collections instead:

```
with BC.Indefinite_Unmanaged_Containers.Collections;
procedure Towers is

   package Abstract_Main_Nodes
   is new BC.Indefinite_Unmanaged_Containers (String);
   package Main_Nodes is new Abstract_Main_Nodes.Collections;

   package Abstract_All_Main_Nodes
   is new BC.Indefinite_Unmanaged_Containers (Main_Nodes.Collection,
                                              "=" => Main_Nodes."=");
   package All_Main_Nodes is new Abstract_All_Main_Nodes.Collections;

end Towers;
```

and

```
with Towers; use Towers;
procedure Main is

   Main_Tower : Main_Nodes.Collection;
   Main_Towers : All_Main_Nodes.Collection;

begin

   Main_Nodes.Append (Main_Tower, "A");
   Main_Nodes.Append (Main_Tower, "B");
   Main_Nodes.Append (Main_Tower, "D");
   Main_Nodes.Append (Main_Tower, "E");
   Main_Nodes.Append (Main_Tower, "F");
   All_Main_Nodes.Append (Main_Towers, Main_Tower);

   Main_Nodes.Clear (Main_Tower);
   Main_Nodes.Append (Main_Tower, "C");
```

etc.

Comment: The professor's notes (http://cs.fit.edu/~ryan/cse4250/hear.html) for the exercise are very explicit about why Ada 2005 shouldn't be used.

Comment: Since part of the exercise is to write your own generic linked list, this answer is irrelevant! And, note, the professor didn't say not to use Ada >= 2005; just not to use `Ada.Containers.Linked_Lists`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the [full project description](http://cs.fit.edu/~ryan/cse4250/hear.html) - just so we know what the task is.

The ban on using `package Ada.Containers.Doubly_Linked_Lists` can be seen as an irelevant distraction.

One thing I've noticed, which may simplify the task is that there is not mention whatsoever of communications links being removed/disappearing.

Another nice detail of the problem description is that there are no performance requirements.

The only tasks your abstract data structure should be able to handle are:

- Add a directional link from one node to another.
- Answer if there is a directional link from one node to another.

(I'm not going to tell you more, as I don't want you to get in too much trouble with your professor.)

Comment: The instructions say "Write a generic linked-list package and use it to implement the adjacency-list representation of a graph to solve the problem."